# Why do my HTML templates append to the same DIV container?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to append two different templates to two separate div containers respectively. But both templates are applying only to the first DIV container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="cont1">
  </div>

  <div id="cont2">
  </div>


  <button onclick="showSection('container1', true)">Container1</button>
  <button onclick="showSection('container2', true)">Container2</button>

  <template id="container1"><p>This should be in container1</p></template>
  <template id="container2"><p>This should be in container2</p></template>

</body>
<script>
  function showSection(templateId,repeat){
    var temp = document.getElementById(templateId);
    var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(repeat);
    if(templateId="container1"){
      var divId = "cont1"
      var position = document.getElementById(divId);
      position.appendChild(clon);    
    }  
    if(templateId="container2"){
      var divId = "cont2"
      var position = document.getElementById(divId);
      position.appendChild(clon);    
    }  
  }
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Yet:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: `if(templateId=="container1")`

Comment: in other words ... use `==` or `===` for comparison ... `=` is assignment, and since `"container1"` is truthy, the first if condition is always run

Comment: Good lord! How embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple actually, I think you might kick yourself ;)

It's as simple as changing:

```
if(templateId="container1"){
```

to

```
if(templateId=="container1"){
```

Using `=` and using `==` mean two very different things.

Single = is an assignment operator and will always equate to true in an if statement (assuming it is a non negative value).

Double or tripple =, as in == and ===, is a comparison and will equate to true only if the values on either side of the operator are equal.

You can find a new working exmaple below

You'll see I've also changed the second `if` to an `else if`, this is just to make your code a little bit more efficient, more readable, and will probably yeild 'truer' results to what you're trying to achieve but is not necessary

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="cont1">
  </div>

  <div id="cont2">
  </div>


  <button onclick="showSection('container1', true)">Container1</button>
  <button onclick="showSection('container2', true)">Container2</button>

  <template id="container1"><p>This should be in container1</p></template>
  <template id="container2"><p>This should be in container2</p></template>

</body>
<script>
  function showSection(templateId,repeat){
    var temp = document.getElementById(templateId);
    var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(repeat);
    if(templateId=="container1"){
      var divId = "cont1"
      var position = document.getElementById(divId);
      position.appendChild(clon);    
    } else if(templateId=="container2"){
      var divId = "cont2"
      var position = document.getElementById(divId);
      position.appendChild(clon);    
    }  
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I could have sworn I found a bug in Chrome... LOL